# flash() method doesn't work as expected

Tags: redirect, cakephp-1.3

Bear with me as I'm working on a project in an older cake 1.3 install. In my controller, I have this: `$this->flash('Thank you for contacting us.  One of our managers will contact you soon.', '/m', 5000);`.  Upon submitting a form, my controller properly redirects the user, but it 1)doesn't pause for 5 seconds 2)doesn't flash my message.  Do I actually have to add some call to flash() in my view?  Do I need to specify that the controller use the Session helper? I'm unsure what it is that I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**  Tried `<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>`   in my view, which shows my success message upon submitting the form...and then it never redirects.  So.  Yeah.

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm thinking in milliseconds.  I should put 5 instead of 5000, probably.  Any php-ers out there who can confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flash is

```
flash( $message, $url, $pause = 1, $layout = 'flash' )
```

Also note that when debug is on, redirect does not auto redirect, you actually have to click the link. when debug is at 0, it will auto redirect after the time is up.

Comment: Didn't know that about when debug is anything other than 0, thanks for the tip!